# Commit na branch errada

Tags: git, versionamento

Eu fiz um commit em uma branch errada e por conta disso não consigo mais dar push em uma branch específica porque não aparece mais os arquivos que foram modificados. Como posso fazer uma modificação forçada e subir essas alterações para minha branch?

Comment: No branch que você deu commit, contem informações que você pode jogar no repositório principal?

Answer (score 1):

1- Faça backup do que você fez.

2- `git checkout .`

3- `git checkout [branch_desejada]`

4- `git push origin [branch_desejada]`